# How to add extra columns to a relational database table?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a table **ABC** which has some core columns. I want to have some extra columns depending on the user. E.g. **user1** may have columns **b, c, d** while **user2** may have columns **c, d, f**.

Should I add the columns in the same table (**ABC**) or should I have **another table just for extra columns** where each **row represents a column** having the following structure:

| **ABCId** | **Column Name** | **Column Value** |

Answer (score 0):

Either approach is viable.

The advantages of having the columns in one table is basically simplicity.  It is easy to access the columns.  And where a record does not use the columns, the values are `NULL`.

The downside might be performance.  Fixed-width data types such as integers will usually occupy space on the data page, even when `NULL` (although this depends on the database).   So, unused values still make the record larger.  (This may or may not be true of strings.) Wider records require more space which can reduce database performance for some operations. This would not be an issue in columnar databases.

The alternative is to have a separate table.  Because there is a one-to-one relationship, the two tables should have the same primary key.  That is also feasible -- and is probably a performance win in two cases:

- When most of the rows do not have values in the columns.
- When many queries do not need the additional columns.

But both approaches are reasonable.  Depending on other factors, one or the other might be more reasonable.

Comment: @Gorgon Linoff I tried having a separate table but that becomes performance bottle neck to having row based column. Because lets say a user has 20 extra column on average that means 20 rows in the extra columns table. Joining these 2 tables when the users are 2 million brings the server to its knees.

Comment: @ShiranAbbasi . . . I would suggest that both tables have the same primary key.

Comment: @Gorgon Linoff how can it happen? Because the extra columns table will have repeated ids from the main table for different column values

Comment: @ShiranAbbasi . . . A table can have a primary key that is a foreign key reference to another table.

Comment: @Gorgon Linoff in this case foreign key can't become primary key because it will repeat. ABCId will repeat for multiple extra columns.